# Symfony 1.4: in action, I do a raw query, the first record gets lost

Tags: database, orm, symfony1

I'm in an action and do a raw query:

```
   $res = Propel::getConnection()->prepare('adasasd');
   $res->execute();
```

then I'm doing a "foreach"

```
 while ($rec = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
 {
 }
```

it turns out the first records doesn't list here. It somehow gets lost.

However, if I do it right after the ->execute(), all records are available. But if I'm doing it in the view, even in the first line, the 1st record is missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe its the cursor_offset on the fetch function ([Fetch function php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) try setting it to 0 like

```
while ($rec = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ,0)){...}
```

One thing i found out reading php manual its that there is a function called [PDOStatement::fetchObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) (they say its an alternative, also one thing you could try out).

FInally I would really recomment to use the fetchAll if you are planning on iterating over all the resutls:

```
foreach($res->fetchAll(PDO) as $result)
{

}
```